# Access a ID3D11Texture2D in another thread

Tags: directx, directx11, multithreading

I created a `ID3D11Texture2D` texture on a thread with DirectX graphics and I passed its pointer to a worker thread. I'm assured that the creator thread will no longer reference nor use the texture. I now need the worker thread to copy the resource

```
pContext->CopyResource(..);
```

What's the correct way of doing this in the worker thread?

In other frameworks like CUDA or OpenGL I would just push/restore the creator thread's context into the worker thread, but I'm not sure if that applies in DirectX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods on the DirectX 11 Device are thread-safe, but methods on the DirectX 11 DeviceContext are not.

**In other words, the application must manage the thread-safety when sharing the immediate context between threads.**

See [MSDN: Introduction to Multithreading in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891.aspx)

Comment: Would creating a shared handle to the resource underlying that texture work? i.e. `CreateSharedHandle` and pass that handle to the other thread with another context of its own

Comment: There's no automatic synchronization of shared handles either. Your application has to ensure the thread-safety directly.